# Rails - Duplicating models with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am trying to duplicate a model and its associated records like this:

```
tmp = self.dup
self.revisions.each do |r|
  tmp.revisions << r.dup
end
tmp.save
```

which doesn't seem to work as expected.  If I remove the portion of code that duplicates the revisions, it makes a copy just fine, but I need those associated record copied as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not saving the duplicated revisions

Comment: @japed Adding a save inside the do block doesn't work either.  In my log, I just get a bunch of begin, rollback, commit messages but nothing is duplicated.

Comment: Thinking about it you'd need to save the tmp record first otherwise you can't save the revisions as the tmp doesn't exist

Comment: Yup, I tried that as well.

Comment: Can you post the rollback and commit error messages?